# how can i prove that the sorgenfrey line is not sigma compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Can someone give me a hint to prove that the sorgenfrey line is not sigma compact?
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Bbb S$ be the Sorgenfrey line. One way is to show that if $\Bbb S$ were $\sigma$-compact, $\Bbb S\times\Bbb S$ would also be $\sigma$-compact and therefore Lindelöf; $\Bbb S\times\Bbb S$, however, is not Lindelöf. Another is to show that compact subsets of $\Bbb S$ are nowhere dense in the Euclidean topology and then use the Baire category theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.** Use the fact that every uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a two-sided limit point (if you didn't know this, show it!).

Then take a $S_0 \subset S$, the Sorgenfrey Line, be a compact subspace that is uncountable. Use the lemma and find a convergent sequence in $S_0$. Can you use this to help yourself find a open cover with no finite subcover?

What can you then conclude?